# Will MSVC 2010 reorder function calls when whole program optimization is enabled?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

Is the compiler allowed to reorder function calls when whole program optimization is enabled? (/GL switch)

Wouldn't that break code in multithreaded environments?

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
Thread1
{
  numbers.append( 1 );
  numbers.append( 2 );
  numbers.append( 3 );

  numbers.append( 1 );
  numbers.append( 2 );
  numbers.append( 3 );

  manager.signalFinished();
}

Thread2
{
  // is the compiler allowed to reorder the next two lines?

  bool isReady = manager.isFinished();
  int lastElem = numbers.getLastElement();

  if( 3 == lastElem )
  {
    if( isReady )
    {
      TerminateThread();
    }
    else
    {
      // go back to start
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

We have a total number of 2 threads.

Thread 1 will put numbers in a list and once finished, trigger a signal that all numbers are in the list.
Assume that for a complete list, the last element always has to be `3`.

Thread 2 will check whether the signal is set and whether the last element is `3`.

Assuming that all functions are in different compilation units, the program should run just fine.

If whole program optimization would enable the compiler to reorder function calls ( or to execute them in parallel ), this program would be likely to be broken.
The first two lines of Thread 2 seem unrelated to the compiler ( they do **not** share a mutex ), whereas they are actually linked logically on a deep level.

The reordering could lead to the situation:

```
Thread1: numbers.append( 1 );
         numbers.append( 2 );
         numbers.append( 3 );

Thread2: int lastElem = numbers.getLastElement(); // is 3

Thread1: numbers.append( 1 );
         numbers.append( 2 );
         numbers.append( 3 );
         manager.signalFinished();

Thread2: bool isReady = manager.isFinished(); // is true
         // now TerminateThread would be invoked
         // and the second 1, 2, 3 of Thread1 would be lost
```

Comment: Does `isFinished()` call use any locks or atomics? If yes, then the compiler is not allowed to move reads up before an acquire-and-load. If not, then your program has a data race and exhibits undefined behavior - in which case, the compiler can legally do anything at all.

Comment: It's also suspicious that Thread 2 has to do the signalling on behalf of Thread 1. How does Thread 2 know that? Obviously Thread 1 must have signaled Thread 2, so Thread 2 can signal Thread 3. But why not do so directly?